# Trouble in using Fragments using PagerAdapter for a tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've the following code snippet which is used for Fragments with tabbed activity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class LoginSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginsignup);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()) {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }    
}
```

But I'm getting an error,

**PagerAdapter( ) in PagerAdapter cannot be applied to (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, int)**

How do I solve this error?
Any help will be very much helpful.

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter`, bro

Comment: Class 'Anonymous class derived from FragmentPagerAdapter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getItem(int)' in 'FragmentPagerAdapter'  got this when changed @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 1):

The class `PagerAdapter` do not have any constructor with arguments.

I think you should either use `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` but they also have single argument constructor which takes `FragmentManager` as parameter.

Try:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return null; // return item from your array or list.
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0; //return size of your array of list.
    }
}
```